# How to stream video chunk by chunk in django?

Tags: django, video-streaming, streaming

I was trying to stream video saved on server. I want it to stream chunk by chunk rather than whole video at once.
I found following code to stream video.

```
range_re = re.compile(r'bytes\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d*)',re.I)


class RangeFileWrapper:

    def __init__(self, filelike, blksize=8192, offset=0, length=None):
        self.filelike = filelike
        self.filelike.seek(offset,os.SEEK_SET) 
        self.remaining = length 
        self.blksize = blksize

    def close(self):
        if hasattr(self.filelike, 'close'):
            self.filelike.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.remaining is None:
        
            data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize) #Read data in chunk
            if data:
                return data # Return the chunk of data
            raise StopIteration() # End of file, stop iteration
    
        else:
            if self.remaining<=0:
                raise StopIteration() #No more data to read, stop the iteration
        

        
            data = self.filelike.read(min(self.remaining,self.blksize))
            if not data:
                raise StopIteration() 
            self.remaining -= len(data) #Updates the remaing length
            return data 



def stream_video(request,path):


    range_header = request.META.get('HTTP_RANGE','').strip()


    range_match = range_re.match(range_header)


    size = os.path.getsize(path)  #Retrieve the file size
    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(path)


    content_type = content_type or 'application/octet-stream'  #

    if range_match: 
    
        first_byte,last_byte = range_match.groups()
        first_byte = int(first_byte) if first_byte else 0
        last_byte = int(last_byte) if last_byte else size-1

    
        if last_byte>=size:
            last_byte = size-1

        length = last_byte-first_byte+1

    
        resp = StreamingHttpResponse(
            RangeFileWrapper(open(path,'rb'),offset=first_byte,length=length),
            status=206, #status code for partial content
            content_type=content_type #set the mime type in the response header
        )

        resp['Content-Length'] = str(length) #Set Content-Length header
        resp['Content-Range'] = 'byte %s-%s-%s' % (first_byte,last_byte,size)

    else:
        print(str(size))
        resp = StreamingHttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(path, 'rb')), content_type=content_type)
        resp['Content-Length'] = str(size) #Set the Content-Length header

    resp ['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes'

    return resp
```

And my get method to stream video is.

```
def get (self,request):
    try:
        video_id = request.query_params.get('pk')
        video = get_object_or_404(Video,id=video_id)

        video_path = video.saved_location.path

        resp = stream_video(request,video_path)


        return resp 

    except Exception as e:
        return Response({"success":False,"message":str(e)})
```

When I try to stream video from either postman or browser, It doesn't work and blank screen is shown as in the picture.
[image]

What should I do to stream video properly?

Comment: you might have to narrow the problem down. Are there any error messages? Which part of the code is failing? Have you tried some print commands to see the state?